# How can one see how much time was spent on a review?

Tags: discussion, support, review, review-abuse, time

Is there a way to tell how long a reviewer spent looking at a particular review item?

I have seen people comment about "Reviewer Speedy Squirrel only spent 3 seconds looking at this review item before clicking 'No Action Needed'".  How do they tell?

On the review page I can see an item for "Speedy Squirrel reviewed this 13 hours ago: No Action Needed".  Hovering over "13 hours ago", I can see a full date.  I am presuming that tells the time when 'No Action Needed' was clicked.  But how do I tell when they started the review, or how long they spent on the review page?  Perhaps I'm just blind at the moment, but I've clicked around on everything I can think of and can't see it.

Comment: In the [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) the registered users are tracked by a bot called Closey. After 40 reviews it reports your [average](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/41570?m=24500879#24500879).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If they are doing multiple reviews, then you can measure the time between those reviews. This assumes that you have 10k tools. Then you can see the review history of all users when clicking on reviews. If they aren't doing multiple reviews, then there is no big reason to suspect them of robo-reviewing.

For example, I would find this suspicious:

> user  post2334    Looks OK    14 mins ago 
>  user   post2364    Looks OK    14 mins ago 
>  user   post2718    Looks OK    14 mins ago 
>  user   post2362    Looks OK    14 mins ago 
>  user   post2455    Looks OK    14 mins ago 
>  user   post2354    Looks OK    14 mins ago 
>  user post2487  Looks OK    14 mins ago 
>  user post2682  Looks OK    14 mins ago

Also, if you hover over two consecutive `14 mins ago`, you can calculate the time between  the reviews. I suspect that that is where the users who post the comments get the time from.

If you don't have 10k tools, but you suspect a user of robo-reviewing, you can do the same when going to the reviews tab on that users userpage and subtracting the time on two consecutive reviews. Again, this only works with consecutive reviews, but a robo-reviewer will likely do more than one review.

Comment: The 10k tools aren't even necessary here. If you go to a user's activity page, then **all actions** -> **reviews**, you can see all reviews by a user (e.g. [my own reviews on IoT](https://iot.stackexchange.com/users/12/aurora0001?tab=activity&sort=reviews)) without even being logged in.

Comment: @Aurora0001 That is exactly the purpose of the last paragraph of my answer. However, if you have 10k tools, it is much easier to see it (as I tried to explain with the string of "Looks OK" in my post), otherwise you really have to suspect a user in particular of robo-reviewing.